# Getting xs:timestamp instead of xs:date when client application calls our jax-ws api

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere, jax-ws

We have date restriction in our SOAP API as **xs:date** with pattern as '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'. We are able to test it using SOAP UI and it runs fine. When client application calls our API, we are getting date field value as timestamp due to which our schema validation throws an error and generate SOAP Fault.

We are using JAX-WS specification API to implement our web services (Websphere as an application server) and using WAS default implementation.

In client SOAP logs, date value getting printed as '**1990-01-01**' but in our application SOAP logs it is getting printed as '**1990-01-01T06:00:00.000Z**'. (Client using Metro JAX-WS implementation).
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening due to WebSphere (version 8.5.5, fix pack 16) processing/transforming SOAP XML before handing over to SOAP Handlers. To disable this and having as it is SOAP XML in handlers, we set WAS property `jaxws.payload.highFidelity` as `true`. After this we are getting correct SOAP XML and our XML schema validation works as expected.